# Get first Item in list

Tags: c#, linq, list, ienumerable

I am using this function to get a list of groups

```
public static IEnumerable<QuizGroups> GetGroups(string sectorId)
{

    var Quizes = _QuizDataSource.AllQuizGroups.Where(x => x.Subtitle == sectorId);
    return Quizes;

}
```

But this returns all, I want to return the first group in the list.

How do i change the statement to get the first group?

Comment: Take a look at First or FirstOrDefault

Comment: ... and change the return value to just `QuizGroups`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use First or FirstOfDefault and return enumerable with single element:

```
    public static IEnumerable<QuizGroups> GetGroups(string sectorId)
    {
        return new[]
        {
            _QuizDataSource.AllQuizGroups.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Subtitle == sectorId)
        };
    }
```

Also note:

- If you plan to always return one element only, consider refactoring `GetGroups` method to return `QuizGroups` only.
- `AllQuizGroups` property may be null. Add null-check for that property.
- You should consider using C# Naming Conventions.

  - Local variable names should be Camel Cased; so it should be: `var quizes`.
  - Property `_QuizDataSource` should be renamed to `QuizDataSource` if it is public or `_quizDataSource` or `quizDataSource` if it is private.¹

¹ — It's a heat debate whether to use `_` or not for private fields, read more at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1630844/c-sharp-member-variables-fields-naming-convention

Answer (score 0):

Try `First` or `FirstOrDefault`.

```
public static IEnumerable<QuizGroups> GetGroups(string sectorId)
{

var Quizes = _QuizDataSource.AllQuizGroups.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Subtitle == sectorId);
return Quizes;

}
```

Comment: FirstOrDefault does not return an IEnumerable<>

Comment: it should be `public static QuizGroups getGroups(string sectorId) {...}`

Answer (score 0):

```
public static QuizGroups GetGroups(string sectorId)
{  
     return  QuizDataSource.AllQuizGroups.FirstOrDefault(
               x => x.Subtitle == sectorId);
}
```

or add an indexer to the collection class (assuming `MyQuizGroupsCollection` is the type of `_QuizDataSource`

```
 public class MyQuizGroupsCollection: IEnumerable<QuizGroups>
 {
     // other stuff
     public QuizGroups this[string sectorId]
     { get  { return FirstOrDefault(x => x.Subtitle == sectorId); } }
 }
```

... then you could simply write

```
  var Quizes = _QuizDataSource[sectorId];
```